# Safely replacing a function call in PHP source code

Tags: php

How can I replace all occurrences of `realpath` calls with `realpath_fixed` calls in a PHP source code (safely without breaking it)?

I ended up with `'#realpath(\s*)\((.+)\)#'` but onestly i don't know if this will work all the time.

**EDIT**: I can't edit the source code (deps not under my control) and this should be done in a PHP script while builing a PHAR archive.

```
<?php

foreach (glob(__DIR__.'/test/*.php') as $pathname) {
    $contents = preg_replace(
        '#realpath(\s*)\((.+)\)#',
        'realpath_fixed$1($2)', 
        file_get_contents($pathname)
    );
}
```

Comment: Use a decent editor and it is easy

Comment: Step 1) You use any editor with such feature 2) you do the replace 3) you run your tests after the replace 5) fix any issues 5) done.

Comment: @RiggsFolly sorry forgot to say this should be done in a PHP script before packing all source files in a phar archive.

Comment: Please do not downvote and see my edits

Answer (score 0):

> this should be done in a PHP script before packing all source files in a phar archive.

Then you do this wrong. If for any reason you need some methods substituted, you should wrap them in own implementation i.e. instead of `realpath()` you use `myrealpath()` in all the sources. And when you are about to release and need `realpath` working differently, then you just swap one file that implements `myrealpath()` and phar it. That's it.

**EDIT**

> Of course but i can't replace realpath in 3rd party code.

Thta's changes things a bit. If you control environment you scripts run at, then you may consider using [APD extension](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/apd.setup.php) which offers [rename_function()](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.rename-function.php) or [runkit](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/ref.runkit.php) and its [runkit_function_redefine()](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.runkit-function-redefine.php).

If not, then I'd check how many `realpath()`s is in 3rd party libraries. If not that many and they do not change that often, then I'd probably craft patched version of these libs to use my `myrealpath()` instead. I still see this safer than global automated source search/replace.

**EDIT 2**

> https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=52769

So it's all about phar. Maybe you shall just consider simply abandoning phar and distribute your code as regular composer package instead? Composer [can deal with many type of repositories](https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md) (i.e. zip file), so you do not have to push your code to packagist if it is proprietary.

Comment: Of course but i can't replace realpath in 3rd party code. See for example https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/issues/526 where realpath will return false inside a Phar archive and this can cause al lot of problems

Comment: ok, so you want to alter not only your code. That was missing from the question

Comment: Right on @MarcinOrlowski you tell him

Comment: @gremo Why can't you change the 3rd party code.  Almost all php code is plain source and if its on Github fork it and change the code you need to change.  Thats what open source is for.

Comment: @TobyAllen beause dependencies are managed using composer and could be updated in future - ie project should continue to work

Comment: BTW can you tell what's wrong with `realpath()` that you cannot use it as it is?